# How to run a java program with multiple classes and packages from command line?

Tags: java

At the moment I am looking for another way to run my Java program from command line, other than  adding it to a JAR file. My program has the following number of classes:

The name of the program file - MyProgram
Main class - Server1
second class - Client Handler
Package name - Items
3rd class - User1
4th class - User2

The main class and client handler alongside the package will have to run first in order for user 1  & user 2 to run, because they are client classes and are dependent on the main class.

Answer (score 2):

Run java classname. As long as all .class files are there java will find them. Just watch out for when usin packages, then you should run java from the package root and type the class name prefixed with the right package.

If you have jar files that you need you should specify them with -classpath when running java.